# How to loop through all the rows and cells in an excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to use foreach to iterate through all the cells in my excel file in order to set a single foreground color. This is what I have so far.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

for (HSSFRow myrow : sheet){
    for (HSSFCell mycell : myrow){
        //set foreground color here
    }
}
```

The problem is for the statements `for (HSSFRow myrow : sheet)` and `for (HSSFCell mycell : myrow)` I am getting:

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of `java.lang.Iterable`

I checked `HSSFSheet` and `HSSFRow` - they implement `java.lang.Iterable(Row)` and `java.lang.Iterable(Cell)` respectively.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this. It compiles ok

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

for (Row myrow : sheet) {
    for (Cell mycell : myrow) {
        //set foreground color here
    }
}
```

I am using [POI 3.7 Stable](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.7)

Comment: weird it does not compile in mine. these are the poi imports i added: 


<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow"%>

Comment: for the above to compile you need the regular `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell` and `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row`

Comment: cannot import those 2 though. "The import org.apache.poi.ss cannot be 
  resolved"
but i guess that a different problem altogether. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you might not have configured the poi jars correctly. If you able to import the HSSFRow then you should be able to do so for Row as well. Which version are you using?

Comment: i have 2.5.1 installed. can i know what version you are using? i extracted the jar file and mine does no seem to have the "ss" folder containing Row and Cell

Comment: yep that is your problem. The example above works with 3.7, and the docs you were reading are most likely for 3.7

Comment: Just wondering, how does 'Row myrow : sheet' work? should it not be 'Row myrow : sheet.getRows()'?

Answer (score 12):

Please consider using stream for a more declarative style iteration:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("filename.xlsx"));    
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

StreamSupport.stream(sheet.spliterator(), false)
         .filter(...)
         .map(...)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a common for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    final Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
        final Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        // do stuff to each cell here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the [difference](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Difference-of-getLastRowNum-and-getPhysicalNumberOfRows-td5723176.html) between `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` and `getLastRowNum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to keep the things in simplest possible way - to loop through all rows and columns :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcelTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        // Read input file
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample.xlsx");

        XSSFWorkbook wbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wbook.getSheetAt(0);
        
        // formatter for all your data to string (in this example) from date/number etc
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        
        // Below code is self explanatory

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // Since I needed only five columns, I hardcoded the column numbers
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)));
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(1)));
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2)));
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(3)));
            System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(4)));

        }

    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I used the latest POI as on date:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```