# Apache POI "smart drag copy" cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I was wondering if there is any function in the Apache POI project that represents the functionality that is given in Excel by dragging a certain cell at the bottom right corner in order to "smart copy" the cell's content / formula.

[image]

In particular, I want to avoid the programming effort to generate the formula's string all over again for each and every row.

I didn't find anything like that in the POI documentation.

Thanks already,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not.  Because that's a feature of Excel's UI not something that's a document feature.  But you shouldn't need it.  Use a for loop to [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424428/160256) over the rows, and change the string as necessary.  If your string is particularly cumbersome for simple replacements, you could consider a templating engine like [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/).